# Which function is more efficient?

Tags: arrays, performance, caching, matrix

Which function is more efficient?

```
int rows=20000;
int col=30000;

void func1() {
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
            print(a[i][j]);
    }
}

void func2() {
    for(j=0;j<col;j++) {
        for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
            print(a[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you mean performance then just run them in debugger.

Comment: @madh3, I want to know the reason why one is faster than other?

Comment: in func2 you mean col instead of columns, right?

Comment: I did not know it was such a bad question to have 3 down votes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Performance will probably be better for the first function because the data being accessed is arranged sequentially (or mostly sequentially) in memory. This is faster because doing a read on one memory location will cause adjacent memory locations to be brought into the cache, so when they are read, they will be read much faster than if they weren't in the cache.
_
The reason everyone should really know about things like this is because the performance difference can be absolutely dramatic. About 5 years ago, I was working on optimizing the performance of a project that had code like in the second function. I was able to increase the speed of some loops just like that by a factor of 10 when programming in C by accessing memory sequentially.

Comment: The ordering of the array as stored in memory (the byte ordering) is not necessarily the same on all systems...

Comment: @cdeszaq: This has nothing to do with byte-ordering. It has to do with row-major or column-major ordering on arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more, it depends on how arrays are implemented.

If the array is stored in a row-first order, then func1 is faster, if it is column-first, then func2 is faster.

But, like I said, there isn't really enough info here to give any sort of a good answer.